# Posting standards

Tags: discussion, voting

[Does some textbook on probability use a particular way (described here) of accomplishing the segue into continuous distributions?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/27486/does-some-textbook-on-probability-use-a-particular-way-described-here-of-accom)

The question above currently has four down-votes and three up-votes.

Can anyone explain the reason for the former?

It is difficult not to suspect that anything that suggests something that is even a little bit different from conventional practice is considered satanic and treasonous.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea why folks downvoted. I see a negative comment from one person, so I'd guess that person might have downvoted.

I see that you asked at the question about downvotes. (I'd recommend changing the third word to 'possible'.) I think that's the best place to ask.

I do think that saying why you've downvoted is a courtesy to the author of a question. I hope folks will answer you there.